# can someone please tell me why i am not getting the quote on codepen?

Tags: json

[random quote generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg9J3.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function getQuote(){
     var url = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?";
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
      $(".quote").html(data.quoteText);
    });
    
  };
   $("#newQuote").on("click",function(){
    getQuote();
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "container text-center">
  <h3>Random Quote Generator</h3>
  <p>Some of greatest quotes for thought.</p>
  <div class="quoteBox">
   <span class = "quote"></span><br>
      <span class="auther"></span>
    </div>
       
  <button type = "submit" id = "newQuote" class ="btn btn-default">New quote</button>
 
  </div>
```

it is working while running here but not on codepen. can someone please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys...i got it. since it is the unsafe source so without using https, it work just fine.